# ¿Cómo mostrar y editar datos en una misma vista con modelos diferentes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Buen día, espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema.

Estoy realizando el CRUD de varios catálogos, mi back está en wcf y mi front en asp.net mvc. Agregué la referencia del servicio en mi proyecto de asp.net y ya tengo los métodos hechos. En el Controller tengo dos métodos Update, en uno se manda llamar el método del ws para mostrar los datos y en el otro se espera llamar el método del ws para actualizar esos datos.

Aquí el código del Controller...

```
    public ActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        if (Session["Usuario"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            ObtenerEdificio resp = obj.catEdificioObtener(id);

            // Mostrar Update
            return View(resp);
        }            
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(ActualizaEdificio vm)
    {
        ActualizaEdificio entrada = new ActualizaEdificio();
        entrada.Descripcion = vm.Descripcion;
        entrada.Imagen = vm.Imagen;

        RespuestaGeneral resp = obj.catEdificioActualiza(entrada);

        ViewBag.successMessage = resp.Mensaje;

        // Mostrar Index
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Edificio");
    }
```

Como pueden ver en cada uno se manda llamar un método y un modelo diferente, entonces ahí es en donde viene el problema. En mi vista Update agrego el modelo `ObtenerEdificio` y si se muestran los datos, pero no puedo agregar el modelo `ActualizaEdificio` en la misma vista por lo que no se pueden editar los datos.

Aquí dejo el código de mi vista...

```
@model AdministraZion.ServiceReference1.ObtenerEdificio

<div class="panel br-20x panel-default">
    <div class="panel-head">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <i class="icon-layers panel-head-icon text-primary"></i>
            <span class="panel-title-text">Editar Edificio</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Edificio", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(d => d.IdEdificio)
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputDescripcion" class="form-control-label mt-3 ml-5">Nombre:</label>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "ml-2", style = "color:red" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descripcion, "", new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control ml-5", style = "width:92%" })
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer" style="text-align:center">
                <label for="file-upload" class="subir">
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Subir archivo
                </label>
                <input class="block" id="file-upload" onchange='cambiar()' type="file" style='display: none;' name="Imagen" />
                <div id="info"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer" style="text-align:center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn block btn-success mt-3 mb-3" style="width: 30%" name="crear">Guardar <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Entonces espero me puedan ayudar y decir como podría hacer ésta parte y si tienen ejemplos o sitios en los que me pueda apoyar. Gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Aquí está el código de mi WS...

```
        public ObtenerEdificio catEdificioObtener(int idEdificio)
        {
            ObtenerEdificio resultado = new ObtenerEdificio();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("pa_catEdificioObtener", con))
                    {
                        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idEdificio", idEdificio);
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                resultado.IdEdificio = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                                resultado.Descripcion = dr[1].ToString();
                                resultado.Imagen = Path.Combine(urlBaseImagenesSubidas, dr[2].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                guardaLogGeneral("catEdificioObtener Datos", 0, string.Format("{0} , {1}, {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace), "WS");
            }
            return resultado;
        }

        public RespuestaGeneral catEdificioActualiza(ActualizaEdificio cliente)
        {
            RespuestaGeneral resultado = new RespuestaGeneral();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("pa_catEdificioActualiza", con))
                    {
                        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idEdificio", cliente.IdEdificio);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", cliente.Descripcion);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreImagen", cliente.Imagen);

                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                resultado.IdRespuesta = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idRespuesta"].ToString());
                                resultado.Mensaje = dr["mensaje"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                guardaLogGeneral("catEdificioActualiza", cliente.IdEdificio, string.Format("{0} , {1}, {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace), "");
                resultado.IdRespuesta = 0;
                resultado.Mensaje = "Se produjo un error inesperado: " + ex.Message;
            }
            return resultado;
        }
```

Aquí dejo el código de mis modelos...

```
public class ActualizaEdificio 
{
    public int IdEdificio { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Imagen { get; set; } 
}

public class ObtenerEdificio
{
    public int IdEdificio { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Imagen { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Porque usas dos modelos? Entiendo que los modelos deben compartir las mismas propiedades, Deberias usar el Modelo Edificio, y ahi podes guardar un List<Edificio> y cuando queres actualizar, rellenas el mismo objeto.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en mi web service tengo un método para obtener los datos y otro para editarlos, y para cada método tengo una clase con los parámetros que va a requerir. Y esas clases son las que mando llamar en mi vista. Ya edité mi respuesta con el código de mi ws.

Comment: Si, conozco wcf, pero si vas a trabajar con Edificio como poner un ejemplo, tu inferface deberias ser algo asi [Operation Contract] void updateEdificio(Edificio edificio) y tu listado deberia ser algo asi [OperationContract] List<Edificio> ObtenerEdificios();

Comment: ya entendi tu modelo. Creo que podrias usar Herencia para poder mostrar el mismo modelo en la vista y solo usas las propiedades que quieras

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta los Modelos `ObtenerEdificio` y  `ActualizaEdificio`

Comment: De echo los dos modelos contienen lo mismo y yo creo lo mejor sería, como dices, ocupar uno mismo para los dos métodos pero así los hicieron y quería evitarme tanto trabajo, así que veré como puedo hacer lo de la herencia y si no pruebo con dejar un modelo para los dos métodos. Ya publicaré si me funcionó alguno. Gracias. @RamiroBarone

Comment: Hola @RafaelAcosta, ya está el código de mis modelos en la pregunta.

Comment: puedes crear una interface, para que tus modelo herede de la misma entonces despues podes transformar tu clase en el modelo que quieras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tenés que hacer es recibir en el *POST* el *viewmodel* que mandaste inicialmente. Cuando mostras "Update" utilizás el viewmodel ***ObtenerEdificio***, cuando vuelve esa vista por *POST* en los parámetros pones el mismo viewmodel y así tendrás el objeto con las propiedades cargadas.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ObtenerEdificio vm)
{
    ActualizaEdificio entrada = new ActualizaEdificio();
    entrada.Descripcion = vm.Descripcion;
    entrada.Imagen = vm.Imagen;

    RespuestaGeneral resp = obj.catEdificioActualiza(entrada);

    ViewBag.successMessage = resp.Mensaje;

    // Mostrar Index
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Edificio");
}
```

Comment: Probé con lo que me habían comentado anteriormente y si me funcionó pero era mucho relajo el estar cambiando todo, más porque son muchos catálogos los que tengo y ahora probé ésto que me comentas y me funcionó muy bien y sin tener que cambiar cosas en el back, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra saber que sirvió @MonseMontoya !! Saludos!!